# recursive closures (function generator)

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming, closures, complexity-theory

I have been learning functional programming and I come to idea, to assemble mathematical operators.
`counting -> addition -> multiplication -> power -> ...`  Naturally came out simple and most naive code to express this and it works! Problem is that I really have no idea why it works so well and whit such large outputs.

question is:
What is complexity of this function?

Code is in python:

```
def operator(d):
        if d<=1:
                return lambda x,y:x+y
        else:
                return lambda x,y:reduce(operator(d-1),(x for i in xrange(y)))


#test 
f1 = operator(1)       #f1 is adition
print("f1",f1(50,52))  #50+52

f2 = operator(2)      #f2 is multiplication
print("f2",f2(2,20))  #2*20

f3 = operator(3)      #f3 is power, just look how long output can be
print("f3",f3(4,100)) #4**100 

f4 = operator(4)      #f4 is superpower, this one does not work that well
print("f4",f4(2,6))   #((((2**2)**2)**2)**2)**2

f5 = operator(5)      #f5 do not ask about this one, 
print("f5",f5(2,4))   #
```

output (instantly):

```
('f1', 102)
('f2', 40)
('f3', 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376L)
('f4', 4294967296L)
('f5', 32317006071311007300714876688669951960444102669715484032130345427524655138867890893197201411522913463688717960921898019494119559150490921095088152386448283120630877367300996091750197750389652106796057638384067568276792218642619756161838094338476170470581645852036305042887575891541065808607552399123930385521914333389668342420684974786564569494856176035326322058077805659331026192708460314150258592864177116725943603718461857357598351152301645904403697613233287231227125684710820209725157101726931323469678542580656697935045997268352998638215525166389437335543602135433229604645318478604952148193555853611059596230656L)
```

Comment: Your code is only performing addition operations when recursion is flattened out, so I'd guess Python bignums are *really* efficient with adds.

Comment: @Frederic: The number of additions raises exponentially, though. Still, the magnitude of the numbers presented here is not really breathtaking. I don't see the problem, let alone the specific question.

Comment: You should try to benchmark the number of additions your code does - just change `operator(1)` a bit to increment a variable whenever it is called. As an aside, I have a feeling you might be interested in the [Ackerman function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) :).

Comment: @missingno Ackerman is actually defined other way. For instance operator(4)(2,3) is (2**2)**2 where ACK(4,0) is 2**(2**2)-3

Comment: by the way http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The disassembly tells you that no magic optimizations have been applied here, it's really just a reduce over a genexpr. Python just seems to be up to this task, even if it surprises you.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f3)
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (reduce)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (operator)
              6 LOAD_DEREF               1 (d)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             12 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
             13 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (x)
             19 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7f32d325f830, file "<stdin>", line 5>)
             25 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             28 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (xrange)
             31 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             37 GET_ITER            
             38 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             41 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             44 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you specifically look at your `f5(2,4)` call, it doesn't perform so many operations, actually:

```
>>> counter = 0
>>> def adder(x, y):
...   global counter
...   counter += 1
...   return x + y
... 
>>> def op(d):
...   if d <= 1: return adder
...   return lambda x,y:reduce(op(d-1),(x for i in xrange(y)))
...
>>> op(5)(2,4)
32317006071311007300714876688669951960444102669715484032130345427524655138867890893197201411522913463688717960921898019494119559150490921095088152386448283120630877367300996091750197750389652106796057638384067568276792218642619756161838094338476170470581645852036305042887575891541065808607552399123930385521914333389668342420684974786564569494856176035326322058077805659331026192708460314150258592864177116725943603718461857357598351152301645904403697613233287231227125684710820209725157101726931323469678542580656697935045997268352998638215525166389437335543602135433229604645318478604952148193555853611059596230656L
>>> counter
65035
>>> counter = 0
>>> op(3)(4,100)
>>> counter
297
```

65k additions, let alone the 297 for the exponentiation, are not even worth speaking of when it comes to hilariously optimized modern CPUs, so it's no wonder that this finishes in the blink of an eye. Try increasing one of the arguments to see how this hits the border of quick evaluation *very* rapidly.

By the way, `operator` is a built-in module and you shouldn't name your own functions like that.

Comment: I already knew that, ant this bothers me most. Do you have any idea how to better debug recursive stack, because i do not see how can i implement main loop without closures.

Comment: @ralu: What? I don't get the question.

Comment: Question is, for instance how can i calculate complexity of this function for inputs.

Comment: @ralu: Somehow that follow-up question is totally unrelated to your original "question". Please consider asking this on [math.SE], because it doesn't seem to be programming-related.